# Failures during bulk insertion of records not executing @Future methods

Tags: trigger, future

I have a requirement to populate the GeoCode whenever the Account records are inserted or updated. I have written after insert, after update trigger to fire a geolocation google API it works perfectly fine.

But, I encountered a problem whenever there is a bulk insertion of data as below:

1. Using data loader I try to insert 10 records out of which 8 are successful inserts and 2 failures. At this time trigger has to fire the future method and populate geocode for the 8 inserted records but the code inside the @future method is NOT EXECUTED.

#### Can anyone suggest a work around fix for this.

**Trigger:**

```
trigger SetGeolocation on Account (after insert, after update) {
if(!system.isFuture() && !system.isBatch())

{
    List<Id> calloutIds = new List<Id>();    
    for (Account a : trigger.new)
        {

            calloutIds.add(a.id);
        }
LocationCallouts.getLocation(calloutIds);
}

}
```

**Future Method:**

```
    public class LocationCallouts {

 @future (callout=true)  // future method needed to run callouts from Triggers
  static public void getLocation(List<id> accntIds){
    // gather account info
    List<Account> updateList = new List<Account>();
    for(Account t : [SELECT Street__c, City__c, County__c, Country__c, Postcode__c FROM Account WHERE id =: Id]){

    // create an address string
    String address = '';
    if (t.Street__c!= null)
        address += t.Street__c+', ';
    if (t.City__c!= null)
        address += t.City__c+', ';
    if (t.County__c!= null)
        address += t.County__c+', ';
    if (t.Postcode__c != null)
        address += t.Postcode__c +', ';
    if (t.Country__c!= null)
        address += t.Country__c;

    address = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(address, 'UTF-8');

    // build callout
    Http h = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+address+'&sensor=false');
    req.setMethod('GET');
    req.setTimeout(60000);

    try{
        // callout
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);

        // parse coordinates from response
        JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(res.getBody());
        double lat = null;
        double lon = null;
        while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
            if (parser.getText() == 'coordinates'){
                   parser.nextToken(); // object start
                       String txt = parser.getText();
                       parser.nextToken();
                       if (txt == 'lat')
                           lat = parser.getDoubleValue();
                       else if (txt == 'lng')
                           lon = parser.getDoubleValue();
            }
        }}


        // update coordinates if we get back
        if (lat!= null){
            t.Location__Latitude__s = lat;
            t.Location__Longitude__s = lon;
            updateList.add(t);;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    Database.saveresult[] updatedResults = database.update(updateList,false);
}
}
```

Comment: your callout is passing a list of Ids and your future method is looking for a single Id?

Comment: Why are you using custom address fields ? Why not standard address field ?

Comment: Sorry I have just updated the code. Please see the modified code.   I have a requirement to use custom fields rather than standard.

Comment: Try moving your dml out of the loop. Make it `allOrNone = false`.

Comment: Hi @AdrianLarson,  I have modified the code to do DML out of For Loop. Please see edited code.
but still it did not solve the issue
Please suggest the details